# bash/shell: easiest way to get kernel name components on command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, kernel, version

On my Fedora machine I sometimes need to find out certain components of the kernel name, e.g.

```
VERSION=3.18.9-200.fc21
VERSION_ARCH=3.18.9-200.fc21.x86_64
SHORT_VERSION=3.18
DIST_VERSION=fc21
EXTRAVERSION = -200.fc21.x86_64
```

I know `uname` `-a`/`-r`/`-m` but these give me not all the components I need.

Of course I can just disassemble `uname -r` e.g.

```
KERNEL_VERSION_ARCH=$(uname -r)
KERNEL_VERSION=$(uname -r | cut -d '.' -f 1-4)
KERNEL_SHORT_VERSION=$(uname -r | cut -d '.' -f 1-2)
KERNEL_DIST_VERSION=$(uname -r | cut -d '.' -f 4)
EXTRAVERSION="-$(uname -r | cut -d '-' -f 2)"
```

But this seems very cumbersome and not future-safe to me.

**Question:** is there an elegant way (i.e. more readable and distribution aware) to get all kernel version/name components I need?

Nice would be s.th. like

```
kernel-ver -f "%M.%m.%p-%e.%a"
3.19.4-200.fc21.x86_64
kernel-ver -f "%M.%m"
3.19
kernel-ver -f "%d"
fc21
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course the `uname -r` part would need a bit sed/awk/grep magic. But there are some other options you can try:

- `cat /etc/os-release`
- `cat /etc/lsb-release`
- Since it's fedora you can try: `cat /etc/fedora-release`
- `lsb_release -a` is also worth a try.
- `cat /proc/version`, but that nearly the same output as `uname -a`

In the files `/etc/*-release` the format is already `VARIABLE=value`, so you could `source` the file directly and access the variables later:

```
$ source /etc/os-release
$ echo $ID
fedora
```

To sum this up a command that should work on every system that combines the above ideas:

```
cat /etc/*_ver* /etc/*-rel* 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: +1 for the nice hints. unfortunately the output does not contain kernel version components or the architecture.

Comment: Mostly the plain architcture you can get with `arch`, but I don't know if that helps you much. However I think you don't come around without grepping the s*** out of `uname` =)